# Kicks author message from the voice when he does a bad command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

hey nice day to everyone! i would like to have a code that if someone called "A" doesnt do a command as expected just kicks that "A" from the voice channel, i would like to introduce my code to make you understand how i want it in my case:

```
const discord = require ("discord.js")
const config = require('../config.json')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const memberTarget = message.mentions.members.first();
 
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS'))
      return message.reply(
        'You have no permission to kick someone!',
      );
  
      if (!message.mentions.members.size) {
        return message.channel.send('You did not mention anybody, so it means you, bye bye');

      }

      message.mentions.members.each((memberTarget) => {
        if (!memberTarget.voice.channel)
          return message.channel.send(`${memberTarget} ESCUADRON ANTI AFK: He is not in the voice chat`);
  
    memberTarget.voice
      .kick()
      .then((member) => message.channel.send(`${member} kicked!`))
      .catch(console.error);
  })};

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'kick'
}
```

In this case, an example would be that a member types !kick something , as we can see he/she did not type @ before the user name, so, bad move, you get kicked xd.

So i want my code to be placed here in this part(this is where i asssume i have to get the code done):

```
if (!message.mentions.members.size) {
        return message.channel.send('You did not mention anybody, so it means you, bye bye');

      }
```

Right here i did put the Return message to make myself better understood, cause as we can see he didnt mention or probably didnt do the right mention,

Ty a lot i would appreciate this help a lot! and i hope i could be as clear as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!message.mentions.members.size) {
   message.channel.send('You did not mention anybody, so it means you, bye bye');
   message.member.voice.kick();
   return;
}
```